# Reference request about the parabolic Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, parabolic-pde, fractional-calculus, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I am looking for a reference where the following space is defined and studied :
$$
L^p\left(0, T ; \mathbb{W}_0^{s, p}(U)\right),
$$
where $T>0$, $p\geq 1$, $0<s<1$, $U$ is an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$, and $\mathbb{W}_0^{s, p}(U)$ is the fractional Sobolev space defined as the completion of $\mathcal{C}^\infty_c(U)$ with respect to the norm
$$
||\phi||=\left(\int_U|\phi(x)|^p d x+\int_U\int_U \frac{|\phi(x)-\phi(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{N+p s}} d x d y\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}
$$
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This space specifically I don't know but you can find more information on the more general space $L^p(0,T; X)$, for $X$ a Banach space, in the first chapter of "An Introduction to Semilinear Evolution Equations" by T. Cazenave, A. Haraux and Y. Martel.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I ve just discovered this interesting book thanks to you.

Comment: It is a very interesting book indeed! You are very welcome.